# Update all external references within pptx structure

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to update charts within a PPTX file by modifying a referenced excel source file.

My attempt is to modify the excel source file and then updating all external chart references of the pptx:

```
   using (PresentationDocument document = PresentationDocument.Open(fHandler.path, false))
            {
                foreach (PackagePart p in document.Package.GetParts())
                {
                    foreach (PackageRelationship r in p.GetRelationships())
                    {
                        Uri ut = r.TargetUri; //<- set path to new excel ref. file
                    }
                }
            }
```

That is not working as the Uris cannot be modified.

What is a good practice with openxml to change external references?
Thanks a lot for support
Felix

Answer (score 0):

It seems not easy to do this by using Open XML SDK. If you use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), the external workbook for a chart can be changed as shown below:

```cs
chart.ChartData.SetExternalWorkbook("externalWorkbook.xlsx");
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/slides/net/) | [API Reference](https://apireference.aspose.com/slides) | [Free forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/)

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing.

I work at Aspose.